# Apache VirtualDocumentRoot as a variable

Tags: apache-2.4

Can I use the document root resulting from a VirtualDocumentRoot as a variable in other places in the same VirtualHost?

Take the following VirtualDocumentRoot for example:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/workspaces/%1"
```

The resulting document root from the hostname `test.localhost` is `/var/workspaces/test`. Which is also visible as the document root in the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in php.

So can I use the actual document root in a PutEnv or Define directive in the apache config? Is there a variable in the apache config with the actual document root?

**edit:**

I want to use this for a few different use cases.

I want to set a logging directory for all my applications, so I want to do something like this:

```
SetEnv LOG_DIR ${DOCUMENT_ROOT}/logs/
```

Or I want to point the php-fpm applications in the right direction:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9764${DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1
```

Or set some different directives on a sub directory in the document root:

```
<Directory "${DOCUMENT_ROOT}/bin">
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the other directives you need this resulting `DocumentRoot` for?

Comment: @EsaJokinen I added a few examples of why and how I want to use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'd like to point out that the desired state of your use cases might have certain security issues.

Why would you like to store logs inside `DocumentRoot`? This increases the risk of exposing logs to public. Of course you can prevent this with a new `<Directory>` directive, but it is easier to keep the logs on different directory. It's also more manageable in the perspective of directory permissions, considering [Log Files Security Warning](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#security):

> Anyone who can write to the directory where Apache httpd is writing a
>   log file can almost certainly gain access to the uid that the server
>   is started as, which is normally root. Do NOT give people write access
>   to the directory the logs are stored in without being aware of the
>   consequences; see the security tips document for details.
>
> In addition, log files may contain information supplied directly by
>   the client, without escaping. Therefore, it is possible for malicious
>   clients to insert control-characters in the log files, so care must be
>   taken in dealing with raw logs.

On the other hand, you cannot have separated log file for each virtual host if using [mod_vhost_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html). While the motivation for using [Dynamically Configured Mass Virtual Hosting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html) is having only one "wildcard" `VirtualHost` container for all `customer-*.example.com`,

> The main disadvantage is that you cannot have a different log file for
>   each virtual host; however, if you have many virtual hosts, doing this
>   can be a bad idea anyway, because of the [number of file descriptors
>   needed](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/fd-limits.html). It is better to [log to a pipe or a fifo](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#piped), and arrange for the
>   process at the other end to split up the log files into one per
>   virtual host. One example of such a process can be found in the
>   split-logfile utility.

---

It seems that **in this case the setup needs to meet these requirements**:

- you have limited amount of these "workspaces"
- you would like to have the exactly same configuration for every workspace
- the configuration needs to be customized for your special needs
- you would like to make it easier to add more workspaces without adding new `VirtualHost` containers.

Thus, considering all the limitations with [mod_vhost_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html), I'd suggest abandoning it and using **[mod_macro](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_macro.html) instead**, as it would meet the requirements and it's much more flexible.

An example macro with all the examples from your question (even the not recommended `LOG_DIR`):

```
<Macro Workspace $workspace>
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName $workspace.localhost
    DocumentRoot "/var/workspaces/$workspace"

    SetEnv LOG_DIR "/var/workspaces/$workspace/logs/"

    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9764/var/workspaces/$workspace/$1

    <Directory "/var/workspaces/$workspace">
      Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/workspaces/$workspace/logs">
      Require all denied
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
</Macro>
```

Now, you can add all the workspaces with:

```
Use Workspace test
Use Workspace another
Use Workspace third
```

Unlike with [mod_vhost_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) you can still have a custom domain for every workspace. Just modify `<Macro Workspace $workspace $hostname>` and `ServerName $hostname` and you can use the macro with `Use Workspace testwithdomain example.com`.

Comment: Thanks for your lengthy response! The log directory wasn't my biggest concern, and you are absolutely right about the security implications. I won't store my logs in my document root. I also saw the Macro's as a solution but then I still needed to add every site somewhere, which I don't have to do with VirtualDocumentroot. My biggest problem was the ProxyPassMatch, which needed the document root. I worked around this problem by using `SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"` in a `<FilesMatch "\.php$">`.